# Can a flutter variable be used in a php url

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to use the value of a flutter variable in PHP URL.what can I do to pass the value of the variable.

I've tried passing value or can say a id in a web view in flutter but it is printing the string not the value of the variable.

`

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/pre_beta_02/dummy.php?therapist_id=value";

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget{
  //List list;
  String value;
  //NextPage({this.value});

  NextPage({Key key,this.value}):super (key: key);

  @override
  _Nextpagestate createState() => new _Nextpagestate();

}

class _Nextpagestate extends State<NextPage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('${widget.value}'),
      ),
      url: url,


    );
  }


}
```

`

I expect the output as "value = 5" but the actual output coming is "value"

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
return WebviewScaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('${widget.value}'),
  ),
  url: "http://10.0.2.2/pre_beta_02/dummy.php?therapist_id=${widget.value}",
);
```